# If a-b=c, then b+(a????)=c

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a predefined simple sum in code

$a+b=c$

However some of the things that need to call this function (which can't be changed. Its baked into application design) need to be of the format:

$b-a=c$

$b$ is a static pre-determined value.

Is there a way to calculate an alternative value for $b$ so that the original sum will produce the correct answer.

eg:

$25.5 – 3 = 22.5$

$3 + x = 22.5$

$25.5 – 4 = 21.5$

$4 + x = 21.5$

$25.5 – 5 = 20.5$

$5 + x = 20.5$

$25.5 – 6 = 19.5$

$6 + x = 19.5$

What is $x$?

(Sorry about the tag - Its required and there isn't a "basics" option)

Comment: The only formula that will work in general is $x = b - 2a.$ In the first example, $x = 25.5 - 2(3) = 19.5,$ so that $3 + 19.5 = 22.5.$ Is that the kind of answer you're looking for? It seems like a massive workaround.

Comment: Thanks - sort of. I came to the conclusion that it wasn't possible.
See comment on accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your examples, let's say that $25.5 - y = c$

Then you will have $y + (25.5 - 2y) = c$

For example : if $25.5 - 3 = 22.5$, then also : $3 + (25.5 - 6) = 22.5$

So the answer is that $x = 25.5 - 2y$

Comment: Thank you.
You solution is a good fix / work around, but not possible as the 25.5 is a single value and can't be converted to any sort of formulae

I came to the conclusion that what I wanted wasn't possible, but flipping the sign of $b$ got me close enough.

So $3 + (-25.5) = -22.5$ 

The users will have to deal with the negative sign, as it relates to real world distances its effectively the distance from the other side.